# Maven deploy check md5 before deploy

Tags: java, maven

I m using maven 3 and i work on an OSGi project with many module.
Each module have different version, so when someone do a modification, he need to update the version to -SNAPSHOT. But  Sometime people forgot to change the version so when deploy is made, nothing is deploy, and new code is not embeded in the release.
That why i want to overide deploy maven plugin to add a md5 verification only on release jar ( not snapshot because i m sure that they are deployed) and write an log.warn to say "check version for module X because it s seems module have change but version is the same as before"

Currenlty when i doing deploy, i got release jar for a module and i compare md5 with jar in my target directory, but because of MANIFEST, md5 is never the same so i got always my warning.
I change a little the code to check the md5 file by file, and now i can so a report of the different file without checking a list of file (MANIFEST....) 
But if 90% of file have same md5, other not, but if. I open 2 different file, in reality they are identic...just because nexus jar is build on linux and target jar is build on windows...some file differ and many other not...

How can i create a jar build on linux or windows with same md5? Does it possible or it depends on many things like processeur, linux/windows?

Thanks by advance and if you have any other idea to do what i want in other manear...

Comment: First what do you mean by `nothing is deploy,` if they change something than a new SNAPSHOT will be made and that SNAPSHOT has a different timestamp which means a different qualifier in OSGi ?Apart from that a SNAPSHOT can't be integrated into a release...btw: are the versions defined with limits in the MANIFEST or how have they been defined?

Comment: Nothing is deploy if developer forgot to change qualifier  for the bundle. If version is 1.0.0, this version already exist on nexus and mvndeploy don t deploy anyrhing. But developer change java class and is code will never deploy even if we pass the version to 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT. We use maven-bundle-plugin so we don t define static version so we have a default range set by the plugin.

Comment: Are you using tycho ?

Comment: No i m not, we use maven-bundle-plugin to generate jar with manifest, and mvn deploy to push jar on nexus and we have a module that create a features.xml file that we use in karaf to get all jar we have previously deploy on nexus. But as i say, our deploy goal only deploy -SNAPSHOT jar, we don't override realease if already exist. So if someone modify a java file without change the module version to snapshot, deploy will not override nexus jar and  new code is not pushed on nexus...to prevent this i would like to check if md5 of target jar is same as nexus jar and show log on command line

Answer (score 0):

You could improve your release process by not allowing that stable versions are allowed in your commits. In fact, commits should be made in SNAPSHOT versions. So how can you guarantee this? You can write a pre-hook commit that verifies if the pom.xml of this project that is being commited has a SNAPSHOT on his version property.

So before deploying your module, you run your release process, commiting the POM to a stable version. That's what Maven Release Plugin does, for example.

Comment: Yes it s a good solution but if someone forgot to put hook file in his git local, hook will never fire and we can have error again...i would like to put it in maven directly to don t have extern configuration;) but it can be a good temp solution;) thanks or proposal